# Json schema validation fails

Tags: java, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have the following dependencies in my `pom.xml`

```
 <!-- https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema -->
               <dependency>
                   <groupId>com.github.everit-org.json-schema</groupId>
                   <artifactId>org.everit.json.schema</artifactId>
                   <version>1.11.1</version>
               </dependency>

               <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                   <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                   <version>20190722</version>
               </dependency>
```

this is my json schema

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
    "id": "test",
    "title": "test-json validation",
    "description": "This schema should define the structure of the test json",
    "allOf": [
        {
            "$ref": "classpath:/jsonSchema/header/test.json#/definitions/test"
        },
        {
            "$ref": "classpath:/jsonSchema/rows/test.json#/definitions/test"
        }
    ],
    "properties": {
        "version": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                    "2.0",
                    "2.1"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "version"
    ]
}
```

and this is what I am trying to achieve

```
public Schema createSchema(String schemaPath) throws IOException {

        Schema schema = null;
        try (InputStream inputStream = new ClassPathResource(schemaPath).getInputStream()) {
            JSONObject rawSchema = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(inputStream));
            schema = SchemaLoader.load(rawSchema);
        }
        return schema;
    }
```

And I get the following exception:

> SchemaException: classpath:/jsonSchema/header/order_header.json#/definitions/order_header/properties/order_header/properties/origin/properties/locale: expected type is one of Boolean or JsonObject, found: String at org.everit.json.schema.loader.LoadingState.createSchemaException(LoadingState.java:142) at org.everit.json.schema.loader.JsonValue$Multiplexer.multiplexFailure(JsonValue.java:50) at org.everit.json.schema.loader.JsonValue$Multiplexer.lambda$requireAny$1(JsonValue.java:45) at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290) at org.everit.json.schema.loader.JsonValue$Multiplexer.requireAny(JsonValue.java:45) at org.everit.json.schema.loader.SchemaLoader.load(SchemaLoader.java:434) [6x]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values in a `properties` object must be a schema.

In your case, you've put `"string"` as a value.

The error you're seeing is the SCHEMA fails to validate, because it expects to see a Boolean or a JSON object, but gets a string, for the property value of `locale`.